# Add text before a particular position in the cell text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some text in row, I want to insert some text before the first `<` , I know its position by `Find("<",text,1)` But i want to add some text `hello` before it, Is there any easy way to do this.But if it doesn't find the text `<` it shouldn't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SUBSTITUTE` function. For example, if the text you want to change is in A1, you can use the formula below to get the amended text.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"<","hello<",1)
```

The last argument specifies which instance you would like to replace. If "<" is not found in the text, no change is made.

Answer (score 0):

instead of find() use the formula replace()